# Unable to load Controller file in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am unable to access $scope.message in the index.html file. What could be the possible reason? I am not getting any error in the console either and path is also resolved.

Here`s the code:
**ctrlConfig.js**

```
( function() 

{

  angular.module('crudApp',['ngRoute']);

  console.log('called crud')

  crudApp.controller('crud', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {

  $scope.users={};

  $scope.message="We are connected"

  $http.get('/')
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.users = data;
            })
            .error(function(err) {
                console.log('Error: ' + err);
            });
  }]);

  crudApp.config(config);

  crudApp.$inject =['$routeProvider']

  function config($routeProvider)
  {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/',{
        templateUrl:'/public/index.html'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/'
      })

  }

})();
```

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="crudApp">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>CRUD</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="crud">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>CRUD Operation</h1>
      <p>Using Node and Angular JS</p>
      {{message}}
    </div>
    <h3>List of Users</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>------</li>
      <li>------</li>
      <li>------</li>
    </ul>
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" style="width:30%" type="text" ng-model="uname" placeholder="Username">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" style="width:30%" type="text" ng-model="hobbies" placeholder="Hobbies">
      </div>
      <input class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="Add User">
      <input type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
  </div>
  <script type="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="ctrlConfig.js" type="javascript"></script>
</body>
</html
```

I am trying to consume API that will actually display a set of data fetched from the database. That is why I have used $http service here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AngularJS 1.2.0 and later, ngRoute has been moved to its own module.You have to include ngRoute library separately